# Checkbox-Select all toggle and also give individual functionality to each checkboxes

Tags: jquery

I have a list of checkboxes and I want that whenever `select all` is checked, all the checkboxes should be checked and when it is unchecked, all the checkboxes below should be unchecked. But thereafter I also want if the `select all` is not pressed then the value of individual checkboxes should be fetched and appended. `Select All Toggle` is working fine but individual checkboxes get disabled. I want when `select all` is not pressed, individual values of below checkboxes should get fetched.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
    if ($("#chk").is(':checked')) {
      $("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', true);

    } else if ($("#chk").not(':checked')) {
      $("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', false);


      $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
        $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
          alert($(this).append(this.value));

        })

      })

    }


  })


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk" name="check">Select All<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="mango">Mango<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="cherry">Cherry<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="apple">Apple<br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your selector, change `$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {` to `$("#chk").click(function() {`

```js
$("#chk").click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', true);
  } else if ($(this).not(':checked')) {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', false);

  }
});

$("input[type='checkbox']:not('#chk')").click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    var val = $(this).val();
    console.log(val);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk" name="check">Select All<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="mango">Mango<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="cherry">Cherry<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="apple">Apple<br>
<div id="selected"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks man! but where should I add the code to get values of all the checkboxes below `select all`? Tried adding it in place of `console.log` but alert message is `object.object`.